# R subset strange behaviour

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to take subsets of a data frame, but the subset taken is acting oddly.  I cannot figure out how to make my script work.  I don't think the exact contents of Bob are relevant, but zip_3 is in all cases a character.

```
temp0<-subset(Bob,Bob$zip_3==zip_3[i])
temp0$zip_3[4]==zip_3[i]
[1] FALSE

temp0$zip_3[1]==zip_3[i]
[1] FALSE
```

So, it isn't subsetting properly as far as I can tell--if it was temp0 should be true in both cases (and the data just isn't right). Meanwhile, just using a number instead of the list works, though the list is equal to the number:

```
temp0<-subset(Bob,Bob$zip_3==305)

305==zip_3[i]
[1] TRUE

temp0<-subset(Bob,Bob$zip_3==zip_3[i])
```

The first line returns only elements that have zip_3 as 305, while the second doesn't (returns elements where zip_3 are something else).  I haven't had problems taking subsets from a list before.  Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: A sample of your data and the results you're expecting might clarify your question.  Also, you should reformat your code in code blocks, not as quotes.

Comment: You shouldn't use `$` inside `subset` - the whole point of the command is not retyping the data frame name. `[` might be safer the way you are using it: `temp0 <- Bob[Bob$zip_3 == Bob$zip_3[i], ]`. Also what is `i`? And you seem to have a copy `zip_3` *not* in the data frame? Why? That could definitely be causing problems with `subset`. "I haven't had problems taking subsets from a list before" - is it a list or a data frame?

Comment: All of these questions would be clear if you make a reproducible example. You might not think the contents of `Bob` are relevant, but you don't have any glaring typos, so there's not much we can do without data to test on.